# Hide tslint-loader module trace on lint errors

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, tslint

I would like to get rid of the module trace whenever a warning shows up during a Webpack build. I don't know if this trace is coming from `tslint-loader`or webpack, but I assume webpack.

This stacktrace is shown for every file that has one or more lint errors.

The trace looks like this:

```
@ /Users/xyz/src/client/app/pages/app/fake/view/edit-false-layout/edit-false-layout.selectors.ts 2:32-106
 @ /Users/xyz/src/client/app/pages/app/fake/view/edit-false-layout/edit-false-layout.component.ts
 @ /Users/xyz/src/client/app/pages/app/fake/view/fake-shared.module.ts
 @ /Users/xyz/src/client/app/pages/app/fake/service/service.module.ts
 @ /Users/xyz/src/client/app/pages/app/fake/fake.module.ts
 @ /Users/xyz/src/client/app/pages/app/app.module.ts
 @ /Users/xyz/src/client/app/root.module.ts
 @ /Users/xyz/src/client/web.module.ts
 @ /Users/xyz/src/client/main.web.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5555 ./src/client/main.web.ts
```

What I've tried: I played with the `devserver.stats` property, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out this is caused by Webpack2 and can be managed with the `stats` config property.

More precisely `{ moduleTrace: false }`

Docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats